# Binding to a property of a custom converter

Tags: silverlight

I've written a converter BoolToStringConverter. The converter has two properties TrueString and FalseString. Here's how I've used it in XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToStringConverter x:Key="BooleanToStringConverter" TrueString="{Binding Strings.Open, Source={StaticResource MyStrings}}"></local:BooleanToStringConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This compiles ok, but I get an xml parse exception when running it. If I change the setting of the TrueString property to TrueString = "Open" it all works fine.

Here's the converter being used:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="{Binding Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Margin="0,2,10,2"/>
```

Any ideas what is wrong? All I want to do as set a property of a local resource to a localized value.

EDIT Here's my converter class

```
public class BooleanToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public BooleanToStringConverter()
    {
    }

    public string TrueString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string FalseString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return boolValue ? TrueString : FalseString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }     
}
```

Here's the runtime exception message:

A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.dll

Additional information: Set property 'Optimize.Client.Presentation.BooleanToStringConverter.FalseString' threw an exception. [Line: 18 Position: 86]

Comment: Is `TrueString` a dependency property? Can you post the message,inner exception of the xaml parse exception?

Comment: Hi nemesv - thanks for the reply. I've edited my post to include the details you asked for. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind to the `TrueString` and `FalseString` properties. From the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221408%28v=VS.95%29.aspx#setting_properties_data_binding):

> in order to be the target of a binding, the property must be a dependency propert

You can try using the ConverterParameter part of the binding for your xaml

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="{Binding Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=Open}" 
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Margin="0,2,10,2"/>
```

You could also make your converter less generic and only handle Open/Closed strings.

Another option is to have your value converter extend DependencyObject, and convert your properties to DependencyProperties.

Comment: Hi Shawn - thanks for the reply. Probably a silly question, but how exactly can I use the converterparameter part? I don't understand your line: ConverterParameter=Open. Are you saying I can somehow bind my resource strings to the ConverterParameter? Cheers

Comment: You can use a parameterReference as described in this [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converterparameter(v=VS.95).aspx) or one of the options i just put in the post

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I extended my converter to be a DependencyObject and converted the properties to be DependencyProperties as you suggested and it works great! Thanks for your help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the public properties in your XAML like this:

```
<localHelpers:BoolToTextConverter x:Key="boolToTextConverter">
    <localHelpers:BoolToTextConverter.TrueText>
        Sent
    </localHelpers:BoolToTextConverter.TrueText>
    <localHelpers:BoolToTextConverter.FalseText>
        Not Sent
    </localHelpers:BoolToTextConverter.FalseText>
</localHelpers:BoolToTextConverter>
```

The full example is on my blog post [here.](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2012/07/20/Generic-Boolean-to-Text-Converter.aspx)