# How can I make a XAML style override a binding?

Tags: silverlight, windows-runtime

This question is for WinRT, but may also be applicable for Silverlight. Say I have databound the Background property of a ListView/ListBox, but I want a that databinding only to be in place when a particular *theme* is applied. I've implemented themes using [Merged Dictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh968442.aspx) of XAML styles. When a different theme is applied, I want it to be statically defined by the style.

Is there a way to achieve this using XAML only?

I've tried placing the "Style" attribute after "Background" in the ListView tag itself, to see if the order of the properties mattered, but that did not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Nilzor -

This seems like the kind of place where you would use a Custom Converter. In this way, when the binding happens you can run logical tests and any arbitrary code to return the a value that is acceptable for binding.

WinRT project come with an example of the custom converter which i believe is named BooleanToVisibility Converter.

For the record: This does not NEED to be a conversion (i.e. bound object is bool, convert to Visibility and return it to the Visibility property) it can be a logical test -- The bound object is XYZ derives from ABC & if XYZ.Parent.SomeProperty == someValue return different ABC.

Here is a stack overflow link for Creating / Implementing them:
[Binding to a property of a custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234618/binding-to-a-property-of-a-custom-converter)